# AJAX Autofill textfield from php array

Tags: javascript, cordova, json

I'm using PhoneGap to build an iPhone app, and I need to auto-fill textfields with values set on a php array through json.

I'm having an issue figuring out how to call these values from the php file to the html file.

The HTML page (app screen) I would like the textfields to be auto-filled for:

```
<html>
<div data-role="content">   
    Fill in the following to schedule your appointment
        <form name ="appointment "action="" method="POST">
        Name: 
        <input name="name" type="text" id="a_fullname" value="">
        Phone Numer:
        <input name="phone_num" type="text" id="a_phone_num" value="">
        Email Address:
        <input name="email_add" type="text" id="a_email_add" value="">
        Date For Appointment (mm/dd/yyyy):
        <input name="appt_date" type="text">
        Car (Make, Model, Color and Year):
        <input name="car_details" type="text" id="a_car_details" value="">
        Comments:
        <input name="comments" type="text">
        <input name="Submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>     
</div>
```

Essentially, I'd like the Name, Phone Number, Email and Car details to be auto-filled by their corresponding values from the DB.

My php page that gathers the login and basic user info is the following:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$server = "server";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$sql = "SELECT id, uname, pword, fullname, phone_num, email_add, car_details FROM app_login ORDER BY id";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . json_encode($records);

?>
```

How should I structure the script on the html page to call these values from the specific 'id' selected through a login authentication?

My apologies for my ignorance. I've always been very efficient with PHP, but having to use javascript as a middle man to make these apps work has been slightly confusing.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="a_fullname" <?php "value=".$record['fullname'] ?>>
```